# Те кто разбираются в парсинге на питоне, подскажите пожалуйста в чем я накосячил. Код выводит мне пустой список: [] и все. Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, парсер

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# HOST = 'https://rarible.com/'
URL = 'https://foundation.app/profiles?sortBy=users_sort_total_vol_desc'
HEADERS = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36 OPR/83.0.4254.46 (Edition Yx GX)'
}


def get_html(url, params=''):
    r = requests.get(url, timeout=30, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='st--c-cKuOtG st--c-cKuOtG-jAWrS-isInteractive-true st--c-cKuOtG-itrBUU-css')
    autors = []

    for item in items:
        autors.append(
            {
                'title': item.find('div', class_='st--c-PJLV st--c-tRNlc st--c-PJLV-iPjgmb-css').get.text()
            }
        )
    return autors


html = get_html(URL)
print(get_content(html.text))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Везде накосячил, где только мог. Динамический сайт просто так не возмешь. BeautifulSoup здесь тебе не помощник. У тебя два варианта использовать селениум или анализировать трафик сайта.

Comment: `print('st--c-cKuOtG st--c-cKuOtG-jAWrS-isInteractive-true st--c-cKuOtG-itrBUU-css' in html)` возвращает false, а с такими дивами я не готов разбираться...

Comment: спасибо, я пошел гуглить тогда))